# how to print the file names from a folder that comprise the content which has a particular recursive string inside it using java

Tags: java

I have a folder name "New folder" and inside that I have got 3 files. I need to print the file names that contains my name "Sheba" as its content using Java. Can anyone help with this please?

Comment: Please do some documentation research, have a go, and then ask if you still have issues.

Comment: List the files in the folder, read the file contents and look for "Sheba". If you find it print the file name. Now you only have to implement that. Good luck.

Comment: Sure. You can write some code to do that. Come back when you have a specific problem with that code. This is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to list the file in the directory using the listFiles method of Java.io.File.
here is an example, where I put in a list all the file wich name contain Sheeba:

```
     ArrayList<File> findFiles= new ArrayList<File>();
     f = new File("[path2newFolder]");
     File[] paths = f.listFiles();


     for(File path:paths)
     { // getting the files containing Sheeba
        if (path.getName().contains("Sheeba"){
            findFiles.add(path);
        }
     }
```

after that you can list the contents of the files contained in findFiles.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [FileFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileFilter.html) or [FilenameFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/io/FilenameFilter.html) interfaces.

They allow you to get only the files you want when you call the `File.listFiles` method. One advantage of using this instead of filtering the files after getting them is that it is more reusable.

Example:
The filter class (you can create an anonymous one):

```
public class MyFileFilter implements FilenameFilter {
    private String filenamePart;
    public MyFileFilter(String filenamePart) {
        this.filenamePart = filenamePart;
    }
    /**
     * @see java.io.FilenameFilter#accept(java.io.File, java.lang.String)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.contains(filenamePart);
    }
}
```

And you can call it this way:

```
File[] paths = new File("c:\\myParentDirectory").listFiles();
```

Note that you only list the files (and directories) in this the parent directory only. Not in the sub directories.